# Why drag UILabels only to the .m file from storyboard?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

In which cases should i create a property in the .m file? In the past i saw that everybody made them in the .h files. It will be private or why should i use this solution?

```
@interface StatViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *sampleText;
@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to leave a property in the .m file for the `properties` you don't want to make available outside of your class. What you did here is that you are declaring your property in the class continuation (also known as class extension) which is used to define the private interface of your class.

In the scenario you are showing you would leave the `sampleText` property in the header file if you would need to be able to access this outside your class otherwise you can leave it in the class `continuation`.

Comment: Why good is making available a property only in one class? I mean the app will be faster or it has security reasons? Or it's just an option when i don't need a property outside of the class and not a serious technical question?

Comment: In a sense this is more secure because you expose only what is really needed to the outside world when they need to interact with your class. It can also perform faster at the compilation time: if you expose less properties you will import less header files and get a faster compilation time.